# Need Help Understanding Recursive Prefix Evaluator

Tags: c++, recursion, prefix, evaluator

This is a piece of code I found in my textbook for using recursion to evaluate prefix expressions. I'm having trouble understanding this code and the process in which it goes through.

```
    char *a; int i;
    int eval()
      { int x = 0;
        while (a[i] == ' ') i++;
        if (a[i] == '+')
          { i++; return eval() + eval(); }
        if (a[i] == '*')
          { i++; return eval() * eval(); }
        while ((a[i] >= '0') && (a[i] <= '9'))
           x = 10*x + (a[i++] - '0');
        return x;
      }
```

I guess I'm confused primarily with the return statements and how it eventually leads to solving a prefix expression. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One recommendation (because I just stumbled over a post from Eric Lippert) is to separate the technicalities from the logic. I'm paraphrasing Eric here. In your code the important things appear to be indices and chars. But what you are actually doing (and trying to grasp) is to build a model of relations between abstract objects, namely numbers and operators, and evaluate it. (The model happens to be built on the stack, btw. ;-) .) So I'd first transform the text into logical items, i.e. tokens (i.e. lex it), and then deal with those in an abstract fashion. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand recursive examples is to work through an example :

```
char* a = "+11 4"
```

first off, `i` is initialized to 0 because there is no default initializer. `i` is also global, so updates to it will affect all calls of `eval()`.

```
i = 0, a[i] = '+'
```

there are no leading spaces, so the first while loop condition fails. The first if statement succeeds, `i` is incremented to 1 and `eval() + eval()` is executed. We'll evaluate these one at a time, and then come back after we have our results.

```
i = 1, a[1] = '1'
```

Again, no leading spaces, so the first while loop fails. The first and second if statements fail. In the last while loop, '1' is between 0 and 9(based on ascii value), so `x` becomes 0 + a[1] - '0', or 0 + 1 = 1. Important here is that `i` is incremented after `a[i]` is read, then i is incremented. The next iteration of the while loop adds to x. Here x = 10 * 1 + a[2] - '0', or 10 + 1 = 11. With the correct value of `x`, we can exit `eval()` and return the result of the first operand, again here 11.

```
i = 2, a[2] = '4'
```

As in the previous step, the only statement executed in this call of eval() is the last while loop. x = 0 + a[2] - '0', or 0 + 4 = 4. So we return 4.

At this point the control flow returns back to the original call to eval(), and now we have both values for the operands. We simply perform the addition to get 11 + 4 = 15, then return the result.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It definitely helped a lot. I understand a lot more but I'm still confused on how the "return eval() + eval()" piece of code knows where to stop. How does it know to make the last digit "4", in your example", in its own eval? That's the last thing im confused about but I feel that it's crucial to this.

Comment: The first eval() in the "return eval()+eval()" code will start a '1' and end on the space, having captured 11. The second eval() call will strip the space, and then capture the 4, stopping at the null terminator of the string returning 4.

Comment: The behaviour is dangerous, in the `eval() + eval()` expression the order in which the functions are called is not specified. As it uses just `+` and `*` (conmutative operations), this is OK; but add `-` and `/` and all hell can break loose...

Answer (score 1):

Every time eval() is called, it computes the value of the immediate next expression starting at position i, and returns that value.

Within eval:
The first while loop is just to ignore all the spaces.
Then there are 3 cases:

(a) Evaluate expressions starting with a + (i.e. An expression of the form **A+B** which is **"+ A B"** in prefix

(b) Evaluate expressions starting with a * (i.e. **A*B = "* A B"**)

(c) Evaluate integer values (i.e. Any consecutive sequence of digits)

The while loop at the end takes care of case (c).

The code for case (a) is similar to that for case (b). Think about case (a):
If we encounter a + sign, it means we need to add the next two "**things**" we find in the sequence. The "**things**" might be numbers, or may themselves be expressions to be evaluated (such as X+Y or X*Y).

In order to get what these "**things**" are, the function eval() is called with an updated value of i. Each call to eval() will fetch the value of the immediate next expression, and update position i.

Thus, 2 successive calls to eval() obtain the values of the 2 following expressions.
We then apply the + operator to the 2 values, and return the result.

It will help to work through an example such as **"+ * 2 3 * 4 5"**, which is prefix notation for **(2*3)+(4*5)**.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This has definitely gotten a lot more clear to me now. If I wanted to do a postfix evaluator also in recursive, would I just have to go backwards? So have i start at the length of the string and then do "i--"? Or would that not work

Answer (score 0):

So this piece of code can only eat +, *, spaces and numbers. It is supposed to eat one command which can be one of:

```
- + <op1> <op2>
- * <op1> <op2>
<number>
```

It gets a pointer to a string, and a reading position which is incremented as the program goes along that string.

```
   char *a; int i;
    int eval()
      { int x = 0;
        while (a[i] == ' ') i++; // it eats all spaces
        if (a[i] == '+') 
       /* if the program encounters '+', two operands are expected next. 
          The reading position i already points just before the place 
          from which you have to start reading the next operand 
          (which is what first eval() call will do). 
          After the first eval() is finished, 
          the reading position is moved to the begin of the second operand, 
          which will be read during the second eval() call. */
          { i++; return eval() + eval(); }
        if (a[i] == '*') // exactly the same, but for '*' operation.
          { i++; return eval() * eval(); }
        while ((a[i] >= '0') && (a[i] <= '9')) // here it eats all digit until something else is encountered.
           x = 10*x + (a[i++] - '0'); // every time the new digit is read, it multiplies the previously obtained number by 10 and adds the new digit.
        return x; 
        // base case: returning the number. Note that the reading position already moved past it. 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you are given uses a couple of global variables.  They persist outside of the function's scope and must be initialized before calling the function.
i should be initialized to 0 so that you start at the beginning of the string, and the prefix expression is the string in a.

the operator is your prefix and so should be your first non-blank character, if you start with a number (string of numbers) you are done, that is the result.

example: a = " + 15 450"

```
eval() finds '+' at i = 1
    calls eval() 
        which finds '1' at i = 3 and then '5' 
        calculates x = 1 x 10 + 5 
    returns 15
    calls eval() 
        which finds '4' at i = 6 and then '5' and then '0'
        calclulates x = ((4 x 10) + 5) x 10) + 0
    returns 450
    calculates the '+' operator of 15 and 450
returns 465
```

**The returns are either a value found or the result of an operator and the succeeding results found.** So recursively, the function successively looks through the input string and performs the operations until either the string ends or an invalid character is found.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than breaking up code into chunks and so on, i'll try and just explain the concept it as simple as possible.

The eval function always skips spaces so that it points to either a number character ('0'->'9'), an addition ('+') or a multiply ('*') at the current place in the expression string.

If it encounters a number, it proceeds to continue to eat the number digits, until it reaches a non-number digit returning the total result in integer format.

If it encounters operator ('+' and '*') it requires two integers, so eval calls itself twice to get the next two numbers from the expression string and returns that result as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

One hair in the soup may be evaluation order, cf. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP10-C.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+of+subexpressions+or+the+order+in+which+side+effects+take+place.

It is not specified which eval in "eval() + eval()" is, well, evaluated first. That's ok for commutative operators but will fail for - or /, because eval() as a side effect advances the global position counter so that the (in time) second eval gets the (in space) second expression. But that may well be the (in space) first eval.

I think the fix is easy; assign to a temp and compute with that:

```
if (a[i] == '-')
      { i++; int tmp = eval(); return tmp - eval(); }
```